# Как присвоить переменной, то что ввел пользователь

Tags: python, telebot

На каком этапе вывести ответ пользователя в переменную и как правильно это сделать. Нужна переменная с название flight_hours чтобы после использовать ее в функции для расчёта, а также для условий if (к примеру if flight_hours >= "70":)

```
def check_working_days (message: types.Message):
    # проверяем ввел ли число юзер
    if message.text.isdigit() and int(message.text)  >=0 and int(message.text) <=31:
        flight_hours = message.text
        flight_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество летных часов:  ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(flight_hours, check_flight_hours)
    #если не число то повторный ввод
    else:
        working_days = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число рабочих дней в месяце:  ' )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(working_days, check_working_days)

def is_number(stroka: str):
    try:
        float(stroka)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def check_flight_hours (message: types.Message):
    # если не число то повторный ввод
    if is_number(message.text) and float(message.text) >= 0 and int(message.text) <= 90:
        night_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество ночных часов:  " )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(night_hours, check_night_hours)
    # проверяем ввел ли число юзер
    else:
        flight_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество летных часов:  ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(flight_hours, check_flight_hours)
```

Comment: У вас очень хреновое условие `if message.text >= '0'` ибо такие сравнения со строками очень корявые. К примеру `print("2" > "10")` выдаст `True`. Приведите message.text к int `if int(message.text) >= 0`

Comment: Похоже чтобы решить данную задачу, нужно задать вопрос здесь, перейти по похожим и найти решение)) извиняюсь коллеги. Объявил переменную global flight_hours  flight_hours=message.text